# How could I simulate _set_abort_behavior in VC++7 and earlier?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, error-handling, terminate

In Visual C++ when `terminate()` is called the default behavior is to call `abort()` which by default shows a message box and then - after OK button on the message box is pressed - terminates the application. The "shows message box" part is not very good for programs that must work without human interaction since the program just hangs until the button is pressed.

In VC++8 Microsoft introduced [`_set_abort_behavior()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e631wekh(VS.80).aspx) function that can be called at application startup and prohibit showing the message box in `abort()`.

How do I achieve the same in VC++7 and earlier? I could write my custom `terminate()` handler, but what is the best action to invoke inside it so that the program terminates the same way as with `abort()` but without the message box?

Comment: @ChrisBD: The problem with the message box is specific to VC++. I've never heard of VC++ runtime running anywhere except Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the operating system's process terminate function.  TerminateProcess() on Windows.

Comment: +1 - nobugz. This is a good one if were happy for a process to die instantly. Not recommended if you want it to die in a tidy manner though.